# Jquery grid, iterate to read values

Tags: jquery, ajax, grid

I am new to jquery and i am stuck with the below issue.

I have a jquery grid that displays all userid's, usernames and active/inactive indicator.
The indicator is displayed as a checkbox i.e. Active is checked.

User is allowed to toggle the indicators. I have to submit back the updated list and save.
How can i iterate through the grid and submit this. This should be an Ajax submit

Comment: Would you please indicate which grid you are using here?  And/Or add code as an example to allow us to assist you.  Based on your other questions as well, please read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Try this something like this. I have assumed you have a hidden input field for userid in each row of the table.

```
var data = [];
$("tableSelector tr").each(function(){
   data.push({
      userId: $(this).find('input[name=userid]').val(),
      active: $(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')
   });
});


$.ajax({
   url: "urlOfThePageToSubmit",
   data: { userData: data },
   type: 'post',//or get based on requirement
   success: function(){
      //do something after use data is updated.
   }
});
```